# Sharepoint file share search finding associated files with similar file name?

Tags: search, search-results, ootb

I have a file share containing files named like  "abcd.wav" (audio file), and "abcd.txt" (a file containing metadata about the associated "abcd.wav" with the similar name). Every .wav file has a matching .txt file with the same name.

Is there a simple way to point SharePoint 2013 to this file share, and allow users to search the contents of all of the text files and return associated .wav files? For example, if the user searches for account 12345, they would get a list of all text files that contain 12345, along with A LINK to play the associated audio files. For the worst case, if we can't display the matching .wav files, we would probably want to allow the user to open the file share directly and find the matching .wav file manually.

What are our options here? Is there any way to get these results out of the box, or would custom programming be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Custom display template which is setup so that when a search result is one of these txt files that you also create a link to the .wav file by taking the name of the txt file and appending .wav.

Creating a display template is really straight forward and is really a 30 min job.

Matthew's blog does a good job of explaining the process.
http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-customized-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: We ended up not needing the specific functionality after all, but the solution you provided looks appropriate.